Koalaで大きなlist やmapがコンパイルエラーになる
ソースが5000行以上ある、日本語を含むリストまたはmapを定義しようとするとコンパイルエラーになります。行数を減らすとコンパイル可能です。リミットが有るのでしょうか?
最初は多段のmapで書いたのですが、単純なlistに替えても行が多いとダメです。
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 でメモリーを8192まで増やしてみてもエラーは収まりません。
Daemon compilation failed: null
java.lang.Exception
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemonOrFallbackImpl(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction.execute(GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers.kt:76)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)


Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\miyagawa\AndroidStudioProjects\Felica\app\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\trail4you\felica\StationListKt.class (�w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C�������‚���܂���B)


val StationMap = mapOf(
    0 to mapOf(
        0x0 to mapOf(
            0x1 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V2"),
            0x2 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V2-01"),
            0x3 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V2-02"),
            0x4 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V3-01-1"),
            0x5 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V3-01-2"),
            0x6 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V4-01"),
            0x7 to listOf("試験","試験","端末試験用 V4-01-A")
        ),
        0x1 to mapOf(
            0x1 to listOf("東日本旅客鉄道","東海道本","東京"),
            0x2 to listOf("東日本旅客鉄道","東海道本","有楽町"),
            0x3 to listOf("東日本旅客鉄道","東海道本","新橋"),

